# get the data from url in phonegap

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to Phonegap.Iam doing an application in phonegap,here I want to get the data from a particular url.the data is in xml file.Can anyone please help me by suggesting some idea.

Thanks in advance...

```
html>
<head>
<title>Xml file read</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET","http://saletrack.cynere.net/test2.xml", true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
            return request.responseXML;
            // do something with my xml
        }
    }
}
request.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc();
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
  document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br />");
  } 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://saletrack.cynere.net/App.xml", true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
            var myXML = request.responseXML;
            // do something with my xml
        }
    }
}
request.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But it still not working.I have changed the code and the full code used is given in the main question area.Can you please find out the problem.